# Supabase query all posts from followed users that are not liked

Tags: database, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to get all posts from followed users such that the **posts have not been liked by the following user** (aka me).
how can i create a schema and query such a thing in supabase?

My current tables are like this:

```
User Table {
  id        
  username 
}

Follows table {
  followerId 
  followingId 
}

Post table {
  id
  title 
}

liked_by table {
 user_id,
 post_id,
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what do you still need to know? The condition you marked in bold can be applied using NOT EXISTS or NOT IN.

Comment: @JonasMetzler i have done it in sql. but how do i do it in supabase?

Comment: @FarhanHaider If you have the SQL snippet, you can create a wrapper function around it and call it with [Supabase RPC](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming youru `post` table also has `user_id` column where the `user_id` represents user_id of the user who created the post, you can create a postgres function that looks something like this:

```sql
create or replace function not_liked_posts()
returns table(post_id uuid, title text)
as
$func$
    select
        post.id as post_id,
        post.title
    from post
    inner join users on post.user_id = users.id
    where post.user_id in (select followerId from follows where auth.uid() = followingId)
    where post.id not in (select post_id from liked_by where user_id = auth.uid());
$func$
language sql security invoker;
```

Note that `auth.uid()` is a function that Supabase provides out of the box to get the currently signed in user's user id.

Once you create the above function, you should be able to call it using the [`rpc()`](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc) method of Supabase like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .rpc('not_liked_posts')
```